# How does Github calculate the proportion of the languages in the project code?

Tags: github

Projects on GitHub have a **Languages** graph which calculates the proportion of the particular programming language in the project.

[image]

I would naively think, that the most straightforward approach is to traverse over all files with a given extension in the project and sum the number of lines (words or symbols), and then this sum for a particular language is divided by the sum for all languages.

For example if the projects contains `.py` files with `[200, 100, 500]` lines, and the `.cpp` files with `[800, 1600]` lines, I would expect that the calculated ratio would be :

- 66.6% **C++**
- 33.3% **Python**

However, for the image attached, there is much more code (lines/words) in  the `.py` files,  than in the `.ipynb`.

Therefore, there must be a different strategy to calculate the proportion. How exactly?

Comment: How did you count the number of lines in the notebook? A `.ipynb` is a JSON file which also contains all metadata and outputs (images as base64 encoded), so if those lines are counted, it would be much more than the code you actually wrote into the input cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/156653

With [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist/) it uses file sizes to determine the language percentage.

Comment: File size makes sense.